# Preview for create/edit content doesn't work

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, preview

I'm configuring a DRUPAL site web (that it was previously created) and I'm testing the diferent options.

When I create a new content or edit a old content and change anything and then I click on 'Preview' doesn't appear the recent changes (just appear the old values), I have to save it before.

NOTE: I do the accions as ROOT (it not a privilege problem).

Anyone knows what is happened?

Comment: no idea, may be incorrect hoster settings or crashed drupal.

Comment: I have the 6.16 release Drupal. But what kind of 'hoster settings' I have to set?

Answer (score 0):

I think , after you changed any content then you are only clicking preview. [i am assuming] 
you don't click on the save button.
 if you have clicked on saved also and then also its not coming on recent changes then there will be problem in drupal.
 and clear all the caches from browser and also on drupal site.

Comment: When I save I can see the recents changes, no problem. But if I just press 'Preview' I'd like see how it looks like (for example when you post a new topic in drupal.org)